# which in a way they had

Tags: meaning

*Right down the long, broad, straight highway through Altona towards the centre of Hamburg other drivers had heard the same broadcast and were pulling in to the other side of the roads as if driving and listening to the radio had suddenly become mutually exclusive, **which in a way they had**.*

Source: Frederick Forsyth: *The Odessa File*. Corgi Books: London, 1980, p. 12.

Can you please clarify to me the bolded part which does not make much sense to me. The translator of the novel to my native language this passage translates in a sense as: and that was true or that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of "which in a way they had" in the quoted passage is that "driving" and "listening to the radio" had in fact become exclusive in a way, that the drivers could not do both at the same time. This contrasts with the "as if" earlier in the passage. The "as if" says that these two actions were not in fact mutually exclusive, but drivers acted as if they were. but then "which in a way they had" says that in some sense they **had** become exclusive after all.

The translation of this to "and that was true" catches much of the sense, although not the nuance, of this phrase.

For context, The "broadcast" mentioned in the passage was an announcement of the death of US President Kennedy. Presumably drivers found it impossible to continue driving as they listened to and comprehended this very shocking and distressing news.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But the structure "which in a way they had" is odd to me. After "which" I would await the verb.

Comment: @bart-leby it is a specialized structure, although not that uncommon. The verb is "had"